# mysql update statement changed my parameter value

Tags: php, mysql

I have a php script which accepts a couple of parameters and invoke a mysql update. One of the parameters is an integer.  I added breaker point before the mysql update statement is executed and used var_dump.  It showed int(5) but when I verified the result in the database, the value of the updated column show 2016.  The column was defined as INT(11).  I tried to change the column to be tinyint and the value after update became 127. Can anyone tell me what did I do wrong?

```
<?php
header('Location: upd_shpsts.php?shpid=87&stsdesc=abc&stsdate=02/10/2016 4:42PM&ctyid=5');
?>
function UpdShpSts($shpid, $stsdesc, $stsdate, $ctyid) {
$ctyid=intval($ctyid);
var_dump($ctyid);
$usrid = $_SESSION['usr_id'];
$pkgs = array();
$pkgs_query = mysql_query("SELECT pkgid FROM pkg WHERE shpid='$shpid'") or die(mysql_error());
while ($pkg_rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($pkgs_query)) {
    $pkgs[] = array(
        'pkgid'         => $pkg_rows['pkgid']
    );
}
if (!empty($pkgs)) {
    foreach ($pkgs as $pkg) {
        $pkgid = $pkg['pkgid'];

        $timestamp = strtotime($stsdate);
        $statusdate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $timestamp);

        mysql_query("INSERT INTO pkgsts (pkgid, stsdesc, stsdate, ctyid, lastchgby, lastchgat) VALUES('$pkgid', '$stsdesc', '$ctyid', '$statusdate', '$usrid', now())")  or die(mysql_error());
    }
}
```

}

Comment: show your code please (both PHP and SQL queries). You can do this by clicking _edit_ on your original post.

Comment: Can you show the involved code, please?

Comment: i not realy understand your question, but a INTERGER is alway a INTERGER the size has no effect of the stored values. You can olny use the size for padding "0" in the result. You can find it in the Manual under Datatypes https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/data-types/ . So when you use a TINYINT your Value is truncated.

Comment: TINYINT data type can store integer values between -128 and 127.

Comment: Your SQL Update query is probably wrong.

Comment: guys, he is only changing it to TINYINT to test. He originally has it set to INT(11)

Comment: @codegodie **I tried to change the column to be tinyint and the value after update became 127.**

Comment: @devpro I see that statement. and your comment about TINYINT is correct however it is not the main issue. OP obviously wants it set to INT, the changed it to TINYINT to test. The problem is that his update changes his input from `5` to `2016`

Comment: @Jim are you going to update your answer? maybe give us feedback?.. If not I will vote to close it

Comment: @codegodie var_dump() will not return the length of variable what is the result of var_dump(2016) and var_dump("2016")?? M I right???

Comment: CodeGodie was correct.  I changed to tinyint was for debug purpose only.

Comment: We need to see where `$ctyid` is set and passed in to the function you added to the question

Comment: See the PHP, I purposed hardcoded to 5 for the value of ctyid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You switch the columns around in your update statment

```
"INSERT INTO 
pkgsts (pkgid,   stsdesc,    stsdate,    ctyid,    lastchgby, lastchgat) 
VALUES('$pkgid', '$stsdesc', '$ctyid', '$statusdate', '$usrid', now())")
```

Lining your query up like above makes it obvious. Switch `$ctyid` and `$statusdate`

```
"INSERT INTO 
pkgsts (pkgid, stsdesc, stsdate, ctyid, lastchgby, lastchgat) 
VALUES('$pkgid', '$stsdesc', '$statusdate', '$ctyid', '$usrid', now())")
```

So you were trying to insert `2016-10-02 <time>` into an INT field, so MySQL did its best to turn it into an INT, and you ended up with 2016

Comment: Stupid me.  Thanks to all folks. My apologies.

Comment: Cool problem after posting the code @jim-w don't forget to accept the answer